# Preencher vários combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, query

Consigo preencher um combobox com DataTable, mas no meu caso preciso preencher 2 combobox e 1 checkedboxlist com dados de um bd MySQL

```
//formulário cadastro
private void frmCadastroRecibo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Classes.DBconect con = new Classes.DBconect();
    string sqlc = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
    DataTable dtc = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataReader drc = con.returnDataR(sqlc);
    dtc.Load(drc);
    cmbCliente.DisplayMember = "nome";
    cmbCliente.ValueMember = "id";
    cmbCliente.DataSource = dtc;
}

//classe de ligação aplicação e bd
public MySqlDataReader returnDataR(string querySql)
{
    str_sql = querySql;
    MySqlConnection exec = new MySqlConnection();
    exec = abrirBanco();
    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
    comando.CommandText = str_sql.ToString();
    comando.Connection = exec;
    MySqlDataReader sqlReader = comando.ExecuteReader();
    return sqlReader;
}
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Eu costumo fazer um método genérico para isso. Aí eu passo no argumento do método um parâmetro do tipo da combobox e também do checklistbox. Pode ser um método sobrecarreagado. Uma para combo e outro para o checklist.

Comment: infelizmente não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: você precisa preencher os s combobox e o checkedboxlist com os mesmos dados?

Comment: Basta replicar a solução que já tem para outra `ComboBox` e para a `CheckedListBox`, visto que a atribuição do `DataSource` é exatamente igual!

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo simples de como fazer. Aí você adapta conforme sua necessidade.

```
public bool preencheTipo_Usuario(DropDownList dl)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("select ");
            sb.AppendLine("codtipo, descricao_tipo");
            sb.AppendLine("from tbl_tipo_usuario ");

            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection();
            conexao.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conectDarf"].ConnectionString;
            this.cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conexao);

            try
            {
                conexao.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dl.DataSource = dr;
                dl.DataTextField = "descricao_tipo";
                dl.DataValueField = "codtipo";
                dl.DataBind();

                dl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- SELECIONE ---", "-1"));
            }
            catch (Exception excecao)
            {
                Erro = excecao.Message;
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();

            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Porque você usa `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` após abrir a conexão e depois usa `cmd.ExecuteReader();`?

Comment: `DropDownList`? Ele pretende carregar os dados uma `ComboBox` e Uma `CheckListBox`. As Propriedades `DataTextField` e `DataValueField` não fazem parte do Controle `ComboBox` na `namespace System.WindowsForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o mesmo tipo de procedimento usando um `MySqlDataAdapter` para preencher sua `DataTable`. Uma Vez que você tem a tabela preenchida com os dados só utilizar as propriedades da `ComboBox` e da `CheckListBox`:

> - `SuaComboBox.DataSource = sua Tabela;`
> - `SuaComBox.ValueMember = "O campo que você que o rertono";`
> - `SuaComBox.DisplayMember = "O Campo do item que você quer q seja exibido";`

O Controle `CheckListBox` possui as mesmas propriedades.

Uma ilustração do uso da `MySqlDataAdapter`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa Ilustração crie um Método de nome Carregamento que é atribuído ao evento `.Load`, após a inicialização dos Componentes do Formulário, executando as consultas e alimentado os controles.